# Can we use bi-key authentication with dovecot & thunderbird?

Tags: ssh, pam, key-authentication, dovecot, thunderbird

I run the dovecot imap server and use thunderbird as frontend.

The access is password protected, and I see zillion login attempts with leaked passwords. I would like to switch to bi-key authentication and if possible with a FIDO2 physical key too.

Is this possible ?

I currently use bi-keys for ssh authentication and start to use a FIDO2 physical key.

Comment: With "bi-keys", do you mean *two-factor authentication* or something else?

Comment: @telcoM by bi-keys I mean private and public keys as we can so with ssh and the authorized_keys. A 2FA authentication would be a bonus as we could use physical authentication devices (e.g. FIDO2 keys). The goal would be to avoid the password authentication or only as a backup authentication mechanism with a very strong password.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're using with SSH is simply public key authentication.  We call it that even though there are two separate matched keys, the public and the private.

If you want to do that for mail, you can with TLS.  You should be using TLS anyway to protect your data in transit.  The approach is called client certificate authentication.

In TLS, we always authenticate the server, who must sign part of the request with the private key in their certificate.  However, it's less common for the client to also authenticate, but that's exactly what you're wanting to do.  That results in both sides mutually authenticating each other.

Typically, you'll need to create a trusted certificate authority to issue certificates and then you can generate yourself a private key and issue yourself a certificate signed by the CA.  [The Dovecot documentation explains how to do this](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/dovecot_ssl_configuration/).

As for FIDO2 security keys, I'm not aware of any approach to use them.  That's because the authentication mechanisms for IMAP and POP use SASL, and generally SASL doesn't support FIDO2 as an authentication type.  Even in SSH, the use of FIDO2 is an OpenSSH-specific extension which is not standardized.

However, if you're using a YubiKey specifically, it contains support for client certificates through [the PIV application](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Introduction/Certificate_slots.html) and you may be able to use that [with a suitable PKCS#11 library](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-piv-tool/YKCS11/) to store the private key for your client certificate.  In such a case, you'd be unable to authenticate without the security key, since the private key would be generated on the security key and cannot be removed.